# Sortable over event get current droppable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-droppable

When using the over event, how can you get the current droppable? With the current droppable I mean the container hovering over for the moment.

Here is my code to make things clear:

```
$('#widgets-available, #sidebar-drop, #content-drop, #footer-drop').sortable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
        item = ui.item;
        newList = oldList = ui.item.parent().parent();
    },
    over: function(event, ui) {          
        //Get Current droppable??
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

});

Answer (score 2):

by using 'this' in the event something like the following

```
over: function(event, ui) {          
        $(this).find('.numdrag').size(); // give the count of elements with class .numdrag in the drop area 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

... or you could use the properties from the event directly instead of doing a find:

```
   over: function(event) { 
      var myDroppable = event.target; //this is element where it's being dropped 
      var mySortable = event.toElement; //this is the "handle" element that fired the sort event in the first place.
}
```

Hope this works